# Optimal DB for bulk inserts with unique constraint on binary data field

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization, bigdata

I am trying to find the optimal DB for inserting binary data many times, when theres a unique constraint on it - there is a hash identifying each record, that can't be repeated. I'm interested only in inserting the data, receiving a feedback if the data can't be inserted because another record has the same identifying hash. Not going to do anything else with the data - not querying it or anything else (don't want to do aggregations or any computations, etc.).

There is a huge amount of inserts, and I am not sure that a regular SQL DB can keep up with it.

The DB will also constantly grow in size (data will not be deleted. Maybe there will be some kind of retention every few years), so I can't use a DB which has a hard memory limit.

I've tried running on postgres with an index for the binary field, however it was too slow (around 2ms for each insert, inserting as a batch of 50000).

I've also tried mongoDB (which seemed to have a slightly better performance), however it stopped responding after many inserts for an unknown reason.

I have tried to write the hash field as a Base64 coded string instead of a binary field but it didn't work good as well.

Looking for the best simple DB that can support a very large amount of data (Terabytes over time) in good performance for a simple unique constraint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you want a parallel implementation of a hash table.  There are probably libraries for this type of data structure.  However, Stack Overflow is not the place to recommend such an approach.  By the way, 2 ms for a batch insert in Postgres with an index seems slow, unless the column is quite wide.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Where is the place to ask this question?

Comment: . . One place would be https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.